# SQL Server - optimize and increase efficiency of this procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

Azure SQL Server 2016 w/ Azure SQL Database:

We run this procedure once every 24 hours. Execution of this procedure is currently taking on average 10-12 hours a day to run.

Here is the procedure:

```
EXEC PROCEDURE [dbo].[SyncDataFromTransfer]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @taskSourceId bigint,
        @syncBatch uniqueidentifier = newid()

DECLARE curSources cursor
FOR
SELECT  TaskSourceId
FROM    [Transfer].CaptureSync
GROUP BY TaskSourceId

OPEN curSources

FETCH NEXT FROM curSources
INTO @taskSourceId

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

-- insert the rows into the capture table, but do not flag as active
INSERT INTO [Data].Capture (
     [TaskSourceId]
    ,[Identifier]
    ,[IndividualName]
    ,[EntityName]
    ,[Text]
    ,[RawSource]
    ,[CaptureBatch]
    ,[IsActive]
    ,[CaptureDateTime]
    ,[SyncBatchId]
    )
SELECT  [TaskSourceId]
    ,[Identifier]
    ,[IndividualName]
    ,[EntityName]
    ,[Text]
    ,[RawSource]
    ,[CaptureBatch]
    ,0 -- isActive
    ,[CaptureDateTime]
    ,@syncBatch -- SyncBatchId

FROM    [Transfer].CaptureSync
WHERE   TaskSourceId = @taskSourceId

-- flag the new rows as active
UPDATE [Data].Capture
SET IsActive = 1
WHERE TaskSourceId = @taskSourceId
  AND SyncBatchId = @syncBatch

-- remove the existing rows
DELETE [Data].Capture
WHERE TaskSourceId = @taskSourceId
  AND SyncBatchId != @syncBatch

-- get the next source
FETCH NEXT FROM curSources INTO @taskSourceId

END -- end of the cursor

CLOSE curSources
DEALLOCATE curSources

END
GO
```

In a nutshell: `Data.Capture` is our production table which contains all of our latest records. This table is refreshed once every 24 hours (via the above stored procedure) to create a dataset of the latest information. The records in `Data.Capture` are grouped by `TaskSourceId`. One `TaskSourceId` has many records coming from the same web source.

Once every 24 hours, web scrapers write data to the `Transfer.CaptureSync` table, which acts as a holding table. The purpose of this stored procedure is to then go into the records of `Transfer.CaptureSync`, and one `TaskSourceId` at a time, replace the group of records in `Data.Capture` related to that `TaskSourceId`, so we always have the latest information in `Data.Capture` for a given `TaskSourceId`.

However, **not all** `TaskSourceId's` have new records every day, and which ones do, can differ from day to day. So when we don't have new records for a given `TaskSourceId` on a given day, we just want to leave the latest ones alone that are already in `Data.Capture`.

I hope this explanation makes sense - to recap:

1. grab latest information from a website and write to `Transfer.CaptureSync`
2. Replace information in Data.Capture by `TaskSourceId` with information in `Transfer.CaptureSync`.
3. If a group of records for a given `TaskSourceId` does not exist in `Transfer.CaptureSync`, leave the last transferred set of records related to that `TaskSourceId` in `Data.Capture` untouched.

After the process is completed each day, the Transfer.CaptureSync table is truncated.

The `Data.Capture` table is approximately 4 million records, and `Transfer.CaptureSync` table takes in approximately 3 million records per day.

Given all this information, we return to the problem at hand. This procedure takes on average 10-12 hours a day to run, using precious resources for a very long time.

Is this the most efficient and optimal approach to achieve this objective? I realize "most efficient and optimal" is somewhat subjective. I am looking to SQL experts, which I am not, for input.

Comment: I might be missing something but why the update? Couldn't the rows be inserted with IsActive 1? 12 hours seems much longer than it should be. For this proc, it would be most ideal for the `[Data].Capture` table to have a clustered index on `TaskSourceId`. You might try `MERGE` too.

Comment: Rather using cursor approach can't you make a sub table where half of the processed information is fetched and then use that half information to fill your complete query.

Comment: @DanGuzman I already have a clustered index on the primary key column (Capture ID).  As I'm only allowed one Clustered index, do you think it's ok to drop the index on the PK so I can create it for TaskSourceID?

Comment: @vibs2006 I appreciate the suggestion and would like to explore it more.  Might you possibly have a link to an article or other S/O post where I can read more about how to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: @DanGuzman regarding your question on inserting the rows with IsActive already set to 1, I wish I had a good answer for this, and I certainly understand your question.  As you can see from the comment above the first INSERT statement, the person who wrote this procedure explicitly states that the inserted rows need to remain inactive during the insert.  Why?  I truly don't know.

Comment: @Stpete111, I'm reasonably certain the clustered index I suggested will improve performance if this process significantly but that will require changing your existing PK to non-clustered. How that will affect performance of other queries depends on you overall workload.

Comment: @DanGuzman our Azure Search Index depends on the primary key clustered index.  I was fortunately reminded of this via an error message when I tried to drop the index.  It told me that change tracking is turned on, and the only way to drop the index is to turn off change tracking, then drop it.  I don't think this is a good idea due to the Search Index dependency.  How else can I get the TaskSourceId into an index to where it would help?  Can I add the TaskSourceId column to the existing PK clustered index?  Otherwise, I already have a non-clustered index on TaskSourceId, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Stpete111, the change tracking and Azure Search dependencies add [considerations for schema changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/manage-change-tracking-sql-server). Basically, you'll need to disable change tracking before making schema changes. It doesn't seem Azure Search currently allows composite PKs so adding the column to the PK isn't an option here. I think your best option is the non-clustered PK and clustered index on `TaskSourceId`, albeit it's a pain to make the change as you'll need to recreate CT and Azure Search.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at partitioning the tables?

If you partition the Transfer.CaptureSync table and Data.Capture table by TaskSourceId, you should be able to switch in and switch out the partitions. Putting the partition switching as a transaction, the transfer process should be reduced to a few seconds rather than hours while maintaining data integrity

Having thought about it some more :

This is assuming that the tables are the same structure. If not you could have a staging table which is partitioned, with the structure same as the Data.Capture Table. The staging of data should not take much time as all you would be doing is copying the data, without making any specific updates or deletes.

As discussed a sample for partitioning **(make sure you do not do this on production or have any important database called "Playground")** :) :

```
USE [master];
GO
-- Just Creating a dummy database here
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'PlayGround' )
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [Playground] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

    DROP DATABASE [Playground];
END;
GO

CREATE DATABASE Playground;
GO

USE [Playground];
GO
-- Creating the Data Table with required partitions
CREATE SCHEMA [Data] AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

CREATE TABLE [Data].Capture
(
    [TaskSourceId]     INT
    ,[Identifier]      BIGINT
    ,[IndividualName]  VARCHAR(255)
    ,[EntityName]      VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Text]            VARCHAR(400)
    ,[RawSource]       VARCHAR(200)
    ,[CaptureBatch]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,[IsActive]        BIT
    ,[CaptureDateTime] DATETIME2(7)
    ,[SyncBatchId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_DataCapture ( INT )
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_DataCapture
AS PARTITION PF_DataCapture
TO ( [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY] );

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IXC_DataCapture_TaskSourceID
ON [Data].Capture ( TaskSourceId )
ON PS_DataCapture([TaskSourceId]);
GO

-- Creating the Staging Table with required partitions
CREATE SCHEMA Staging AUTHORIZATION DBO;
GO

CREATE TABLE [Staging].Capture
(
    [TaskSourceId]     INT
    ,[Identifier]      BIGINT
    ,[IndividualName]  VARCHAR(255)
    ,[EntityName]      VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Text]            VARCHAR(400)
    ,[RawSource]       VARCHAR(200)
    ,[CaptureBatch]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,[IsActive]        BIT
    ,[CaptureDateTime] DATETIME2(7)
    ,[SyncBatchId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_StagingCapture ( INT )
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_StagingCapture
AS PARTITION PF_StagingCapture
TO ( [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY] );

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IXC_StagingCapture_TaskSourceID
ON [Staging].Capture ( TaskSourceId )
ON PS_StagingCapture([TaskSourceId]);
GO


-- Creating an archive table with required partitions just so that we can easily transfer out of the data table
CREATE SCHEMA Archive AUTHORIZATION DBO;
GO

CREATE TABLE [Archive].Capture
(
    [TaskSourceId]     INT
    ,[Identifier]      BIGINT
    ,[IndividualName]  VARCHAR(255)
    ,[EntityName]      VARCHAR(255)
    ,[Text]            VARCHAR(400)
    ,[RawSource]       VARCHAR(200)
    ,[CaptureBatch]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,[IsActive]        BIT
    ,[CaptureDateTime] DATETIME2(7)
    ,[SyncBatchId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_ArchiveCapture ( INT )
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_ArchiveCapture
AS PARTITION PF_ArchiveCapture
TO ( [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY] );

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IXC_ArchiveCapture_TaskSourceID
ON [Archive].Capture ( TaskSourceId )
ON PS_ArchiveCapture([TaskSourceId]);
GO


--Lets insert some data into the staging table (this can be your population from Transfer.CaptureSync) 
DECLARE @SyncBatchId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

INSERT INTO Staging.[Capture]
(
    [TaskSourceId]
    ,[Identifier]
    ,[IndividualName]
    ,[EntityName]
    ,[Text]
    ,[RawSource]
    ,[CaptureBatch]
    ,[IsActive]
    ,[CaptureDateTime]
    ,[SyncBatchId]
)
VALUES
(
    1                         -- TaskSourceId - int
    ,1                        -- Identifier - bigint
    ,'Insert Name Here'       -- IndividualName - varchar(255)
    ,'Insert EntityName Here' -- EntityName - varchar(255)
    ,'Insert Text Here'       -- Text - varchar(400)
    ,'Insert RawSource Here'  -- RawSource - varchar(200)
    ,NEWID()                  -- CaptureBatch - uniqueidentifier
    ,1                        -- IsActive - bit
    ,SYSDATETIME()            -- CaptureDateTime - datetime2(7)
    ,@SyncBatchId             -- SyncBatchId - uniqueidentifier
)
,(
     3                         -- TaskSourceId - int
     ,4                        -- Identifier - bigint
     ,'Insert Name Here'       -- IndividualName - varchar(255)
     ,'Insert EntityName Here' -- EntityName - varchar(255)
     ,'Insert Text Here'       -- Text - varchar(400)
     ,'Insert RawSource Here'  -- RawSource - varchar(200)
     ,NEWID()                  -- CaptureBatch - uniqueidentifier
     ,1                        -- IsActive - bit
     ,SYSDATETIME()            -- CaptureDateTime - datetime2(7)
     ,@SyncBatchId             -- SyncBatchId - uniqueidentifier
 )
,(
     1                         -- TaskSourceId - int
     ,3                        -- Identifier - bigint
     ,'Insert Name Here'       -- IndividualName - varchar(255)
     ,'Insert EntityName Here' -- EntityName - varchar(255)
     ,'Insert Text Here'       -- Text - varchar(400)
     ,'Insert RawSource Here'  -- RawSource - varchar(200)
     ,NEWID()                  -- CaptureBatch - uniqueidentifier
     ,1                        -- IsActive - bit
     ,SYSDATETIME()            -- CaptureDateTime - datetime2(7)
     ,@SyncBatchId             -- SyncBatchId - uniqueidentifier
 );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE TransferSync
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TaskSourceId INT;
    DECLARE @PartitionNo INT;
    DECLARE @SwitchPartitionSQL VARCHAR(4000);

    DECLARE curSources CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        TaskSourceId
    FROM
        [Staging].Capture
    GROUP BY
        TaskSourceId;

    TRUNCATE TABLE [Archive].[Capture]; -- We need the partitions to be empty on this table

    OPEN curSources;

    FETCH NEXT FROM curSources
    INTO
        @TaskSourceId;

    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Finding the partition number the data for our @TransferSourceID is in
        SELECT
            --OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id)                                             AS TableName
            --,s.name                                                              AS SchemaName
            --,i.name                                                              AS IndexName
            --,p.index_id                                                          AS IndexID
            --,ds.name                                                             AS PartitionScheme
            @PartitionNo = p.partition_number --AS PartitionNumber
        --,fg.name                                                             AS FileGroupName
        --,prv_left.value                                                      AS LowerBoundaryValue
        --,prv_right.value                                                     AS UpperBoundaryValue
        --,CASE pf.boundary_value_on_right WHEN 1 THEN 'RIGHT' ELSE 'LEFT' END AS Range
        --,p.rows                                                              AS Rows
        FROM
            sys.partitions                       AS p
            JOIN sys.objects                     AS o
                ON p.object_id              = o.object_id
            JOIN sys.indexes                     AS i
                ON i.object_id              = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
            JOIN sys.schemas                     AS s
                ON s.schema_id              = o.schema_id
            JOIN sys.data_spaces                 AS ds
                ON ds.data_space_id         = i.data_space_id
            JOIN sys.partition_schemes           AS ps
                ON ps.data_space_id         = ds.data_space_id
            JOIN sys.partition_functions         AS pf
                ON pf.function_id           = ps.function_id
            JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces     AS dds2
                ON dds2.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id AND dds2.destination_id = p.partition_number
            JOIN sys.filegroups                  AS fg
                ON fg.data_space_id         = dds2.data_space_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv_left
                ON ps.function_id           = prv_left.function_id AND prv_left.boundary_id = p.partition_number - 1
            LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv_right
                ON ps.function_id           = prv_right.function_id AND prv_right.boundary_id = p.partition_number
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(p.object_id, 'ISMSShipped') = 0
              AND OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id)               = 'Capture'
              AND SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)               = 'Data'
              AND [prv_left].[value]                     = @TaskSourceId;

        SELECT
            @SwitchPartitionSQL = '
    BEGIN TRAN;
        ALTER TABLE Data.[Capture] SWITCH PARTITION ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @PartitionNo)
                                  + ' TO [Archive].[Capture] PARTITION ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @PartitionNo)
                                  + '
        ALTER TABLE Staging.[Capture] SWITCH PARTITION ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @PartitionNo)
                                  + ' TO [Data].[Capture] PARTITION ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @PartitionNo)
                                  + ' 
    COMMIT TRAN;
    '   ;
        -- Partition switching magic here :)
        --PRINT @SwitchPartitionSQL;

        EXEC ( @SwitchPartitionSQL );

        FETCH NEXT FROM curSources
        INTO
            @TaskSourceId;
    END;

    CLOSE curSources;
    DEALLOCATE curSources;
END;

EXEC [dbo].[TransferSync]
```

Now I have used just three rows, However the switching process is a metadata operation, and is near instantaneous. The process will take approximately the same time whether the Staging table has 3 rows or a million rows

Comment: How identical do the structures of the two tables need to be?  Data.Capture contains all of the columns that Transfer.CaptureSync has but also has more.  Also, would this partitioning approach completely replace the need to use the SyncBatchId approach?  We use that column quite a bit to identify groups of records that came in at the same time.  Would partitioning allow us to accomplish this?  I don't know anything about the partition approach so it's hard to envision.  I guess I need to see how it would fit in exactly with the syntax of the procedure.

Comment: The structures of the two tables need to be exactly the same. I would suggest that you create a staging table with the same structure as the Data.CaptureSync Table.     Using that would allow you to still have the SyncBatchId as you could have that as part of your staging. Let me try and whip up a sample for you

Comment: Ok let me absorb this, experiment with it, and I'll let you know if any questions asap.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[CaptureSync] is truncated each day right so remove the CURSOR , INSERT into [CAPTURE] by joining with [CAPTURESYNC] on TaskSourceId.  This will only affect rows where TaskSourceId exist in [CAPTURESYNC].

You can leave the UPDATE but if you ask around for a business reason for why new rows are inserted with  InActive set to 0 you might not find one.( I can't see a technical reason) If which case amend the INSERT for InActive to 1.

The DELETE should be changed to consider rows with [CAPTURESYNC] on TaskSourceId.

```
Delete C
From Capture C
Inner join DataCapture D on D.TaskSourceId = C.TaskSourceId 
                    And C.SyncBatchId <> @SyncBatch
```